# How many databases can I create on one Google Cloud SQL instance? (mysql)

Tags: mysql, database, google-cloud-platform, limit

It's not exactly stated in the Google cloud documentation.
The Mysql documentation states that there is no limit.
So, is it true that there is no limit to the number of databases that can be created on one Google Cloud SQL instance ?

Answer (score 3):

A quota for the number of databases is not published, but there is a database table limit of 10,000 tables. There is a table size limit of 16 TB. I am not sure but I also think there is a metrics limit of 500 databases.

[Cloud SQL Quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/quotas)